# How to override Ext.Date in Sencha Touch

Tags: date, sencha-touch, overriding, special-characters

In a Sencha 2.3 installation, I'm trying to override the Ext.Date class to implement localized handling of Norwegian dates. I've created a Ext.ux.Date class and listed it under requires in the app.js file.
But my class is never instantiated?

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.Date', {
    override: 'Ext.Date',

    requires: ['Ext.ux.Date'],

    constructor: function (config){
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    dayNames: [
        'S\u00f8ndag',
        'Mandag',
        'Tirsdag',
        'Onsdag',
        'Torsdag',
        'Fredag',
        'L\u00f8rdag'
    ],

    monthNames : [
        'Januar',
        'Februar',
        'Mars',
        'April',
        'Mai',
        'Juni',
        'Juli',
        'August',
        'September',
        'Oktober',
        'November',
        'Desember'
    ]
 });
```

When I check the console, there is an error in the method Ext.ClassManager.createOverride(). The error message is: "Uncaught TypeError: Object[object Object] has no method 'override'" in the "overridenClass.override(data);" line...

```
createOverride: function(className, data, createdFn) {
    var overriddenClassName = data.override,
        requires = Ext.Array.from(data.requires);

    delete data.override;
    delete data.requires;

    this.existCache[className] = true;

    Ext.require(requires, function() {
        // Override the target class right after it's created
        this.onCreated(function() {
            var overridenClass = this.get(overriddenClassName);
            if (overridenClass.singleton) {
                overridenClass.self.override(data);
            }
            else {
                overridenClass.override(data);
            }

            if (createdFn) {
                createdFn.call(overridenClass, overridenClass);
            }
            this.triggerCreated(className);
        }, this, overriddenClassName);
    }, this);

    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You should not put your classes undex `Ext.` namespace (use your own namespace)

2) Check the require statement, it may be causing some problems as the class requires itself

3) Try to use just `extend` instead of `override`

4) Check the [Sencha docs on class system](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/class_system)

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific set of steps that you need to follow for creating an override for a class. [This](http://codesmith.in/overrides-for-classes-in-sencha-touch/) article explains the complete process, with and without using Sencha Architect